What are the shades (vertical lines) in the orthomosaics?
I am an expert on my field.
I work with remote sensing. Mostly UAVs. I collect datasets and extract features from it.
This year, I started collected with the Astro Freefly and the Sony A7RIV sensor (61 MP camera). The flight takes about 55 minutes with 2 changes of batteries. I usually start the flight at around 10 AM. The flight area is approximately 200 acres.
Flight details are: Speed 10m/s, height 120m (400ft), front and side overlap 70%.
This is the only large field that we flight. For some reason there are some lines on the mosaic. This does not happen on smaller fields. As you can see there are 10 lines (shades) in a vertical direction for the first 2 images where flight path is also vertical. Vertical lines are not in the same position every weekly flight. **On last image, flight path is horizontal.
I always follow the same procedure on Agisoft Metashape to the mosaics.




If you did not say that the lines are not at the same place every time I would have thought that they are old ditches that now absorb some moisture.

Just a guess as I have no knowledge about remote sensing mosaics. Could it be due to vignetting effect of your A7/lens combo ? https://sonyalpha.blog/2021/01/12/which-lenses-for-a7riv-part-2-ultra-wide-angle-from-9mm-up-to-24mm/
